# What lies behind the first offset in WinDbg's DumpObject?

Tags: c#, .net, windbg

.NET [has](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Net.Ping/src/System/Net/NetworkInformation/Ping.cs) the `Ping` class. If I load it in WinDbg, I see something along these lines:

```
0:000> !do 2bd0240a590
Name:        Ping
MethodTable: 00007ffcb23d9d28
EEClass:     00007ffcb23e34a8
Tracked Type: false
Size:        80(0x50) bytes
File:        C:\Users\jer_v\source\repos\pingsize\pingsize\bin\Release\net8.0\pingsize.dll
Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
0000000000000000  4000019        8 ...ponentModel.ISite  0 instance 0000000000000000 _site
0000000000000000  400001a       10 ....EventHandlerList  0 instance 0000000000000000 _events
00007ffcb2255fa0  4000018       98        System.Object  0   static 0000000000000000 s_eventDisposed
00007ffcb23dbe98  4000001       18 ...ualResetEventSlim  0 instance 000002bd0240a5e0 _lockObject
00007ffcb22992d0  4000002       20          System.Void  0 instance 0000000000000000 _onPingCompletedDelegate
00007ffcb225d068  4000003       44       System.Boolean  1 instance                0 _disposeRequested
0000000000000000  4000004       28              SZARRAY  0 instance 0000000000000000 _defaultSendBuffer
00007ffcb22992d0  4000005       30          System.Void  0 instance 0000000000000000 _timeoutOrCancellationSource
00007ffcb225d068  4000006       45       System.Boolean  1 instance                0 _canceled
00007ffcb2291188  4000007       40         System.Int32  1 instance                0 _status
00007ffcb22992d0  4000008       38          System.Void  0 instance 0000000000000000 PingCompleted
```

The total size is 80 bytes, which lines up with the fields and a bit of extra padding. I can confirm that using the [ObjectLayoutInspector](https://github.com/SergeyTeplyakov/ObjectLayoutInspector):

```
Type layout for 'Ping'
Size: 64 bytes. Paddings: 2 bytes (%3 of empty space)
|=======================================================================|
| Object Header (8 bytes)                                               |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Method Table Ptr (8 bytes)                                            |
|=======================================================================|
|   0-7: ISite _site (8 bytes)                                          |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  8-15: EventHandlerList _events (8 bytes)                             |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 16-23: ManualResetEventSlim _lockObject (8 bytes)                     |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 24-31: SendOrPostCallback _onPingCompletedDelegate (8 bytes)          |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 32-39: Byte[] _defaultSendBuffer (8 bytes)                            |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 40-47: CancellationTokenSource _timeoutOrCancellationSource (8 bytes) |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 48-55: PingCompletedEventHandler PingCompleted (8 bytes)              |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 56-59: Int32 _status (4 bytes)                                        |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    60: Boolean _disposeRequested (1 byte)                             |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    61: Boolean _canceled (1 byte)                                     |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 62-63: padding (2 bytes)                                              |
|=======================================================================|
```

What I'm interested in is the difference between that initial offset for the `_site` field. In WinDbg it starts at offset 8 but the ObjectLayoutInspector starts it at 0. It's probably fair to say that both points of view are correct but I'd like to know what exactly is stored in offset 0-7 inside WinDbg (64 bit only).

Only the Object Header and the Method Table pointer are not accounted for in WinDbg's representation -- which one of these takes up offset 0-7?

I found [this blog post](https://mycodingplace.wordpress.com/2018/01/10/object-header-get-complicated/) which seems to indicate that the Object Header is stored at a negative offset (-8 bytes) and the Method Table Pointer is at offset 0.

Comment: You already know the answer, it depends on what you consider the "base" of the object.  Could be the first field (object header) which makes sense from the GC's point of view.  Or could be the second field (method table pointer) which makes sense from a debugger's point of view.  Having an object reference point to that field permitted some micro-optimizations that made sense in .NET 1.0, minimizing the un/boxing code.

Comment: @Charlieface I think that's an authoritative enough answer to state that WinDbg considers the Method Table pointer to live in offset 0. Happy to consider that as a duplicate 

Comment: Object header and method table are not 8 bytes but 1 pointer size instead. I.e. it differs from 32 bit and 64 bit. MT is at offset 0 and header is at -1 pointer size